Pymongo list(cursor) taking longer than usual
Super weird but yesterday I was working on this project and it worked fine. Now today, calling list() on the cursor takes about 30 sec, even though neither the data nor the code changed.
def update_data():
    client = MongoClient(connectionStr)
    db = client["myDB"]
    collection = db["data"].find()
    load = list(collection)

The collection has roughly 1000 documents, and the .find() is extremely fast, and while previously the list() took about 1 second, now all of a sudden it's pushing past 30sec and I truly have no idea why.

Is it a remote MongoDB server?  Could the network be lagging?  Could the server be overloaded with other users, etc.?  Do you have plenty of available RAM on your local machine?  Is your local machine working hard on something else?

I was on a free M0 cluster, and after upgrading, the time to complete the list() function has gona back down from 5 min to 2 sec. So it seems the free shared cluster was being over-used by other users.
